# ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm receiving this error on this code.

```
  items = [];

  noticias: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public http: Http) {


    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'http://portalemme2.com.br/SaoJoseAPI/noticias', true);

    this.http.get('http://portalemme2.com.br/SaoJoseAPI/noticias').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(vetor => {
        this.noticias = vetor.noticias;
        console.log(this.noticias[this.items.length])

    });

     for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
       this.items.push(this.noticias[this.items.length]);
    }

  }
```

There is an API that brings me some data and i'm trying to put that on an array with a loop. But I receive this error in that line:

```
this.items.push(this.noticias[this.items.length]);
```

What could it be?

Comment: this is async, so it takes a while for the response to arrive, so your `noticias` is `undefined` in the for loop.

Comment: but I can put "this.noticias" on console.log and it brings me an array before the loop

Comment: Yes, that is correct, but as said, this is async. So read the duplicate as of why it's `undefined` in the `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks! I put the loop inside a Settimeout function, is that correct?

Comment: No it's not recommended, you cannot know how long it takes for the response to arrive, so using timeout isn't good. Whatever you need to do to the data you get, do it inside the callback (`subscribe`) there you are sure that the data is available :)

Comment: Can you show me how to do that? @AJT_82

Comment: As said, do everything you need to do to your data ***inside*** `subscribe`.

Comment: It worked! Thanks

Comment: No problem, you are welcome :)